# Accessing list objects from another asp.net page

Tags: c#, arraylist

I create a list ...

```
private static List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();

public static void Add(int Id, int Quantity)
{
    int[] buying = new int[] {Id, Quantity};
    arrayList.Add(buying);
}
```

Now ideally I want to access these list objects from another page, but its the first time I've really used lists and arrays so I don't know where to start?

any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save the objects's state from one page in Session:

```
Session["arrayList"] = arrayList
```

Access it in another Page:

```
if(Session["arrayList"]!=null)
 List<int[]> arrayList = Session["arrayList"] as List<int[]>;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your List is private. U must do it public
2) Where is this code located?

Comment: This "answer" should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can expose another method like so

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MyArrayList()
{
     return arrayList;
}
```

This way you can only read the elements in the next page. If you want to add any elements then you can use your Add() method.